# Uploading big files to dotnetcore app in Azure fails (404)

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.0

I can't upload big files and I'm not sure if it's still about a size limitation or about a timeout.

On the controller endpoint, I tried all the attributes I found (at once)

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue, BufferBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue)]
        [RequestSizeLimit(int.MaxValue)]
        public async Task UploadForm()
```

During 'ConfigureServices' I also setup this:

```
      services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
            options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
        });
```

But I still get 404 errors after uploading a part of the file (30 MB are already too much).

Then I even tried setting up the kestrel with the following code, but like that the app doesn't even start (502)

```
.UseKestrel((KestrelServerOptions o) =>
            {
                o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                o.Limits.RequestHeadersTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
            })
```

Comment: What are you doing with those files? do you upload them to storage from .net core?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I think he doesn't mean that.

Comment: Yes from there to blob storage, but I thought that's irrelevant...

Comment: @StefanR. reason I ask about this is that i would suggest you to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview so you upload directly to blob storage

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat thanks for your comment. And yes, direct upload would be more efficient and cheaper. But the form I'm uploading contains more than just the file - it's about user and metadata, and for each file I create a database entry with those additional informations. So far the application is stable and approved, and in order to separate this data for more efficient upload, I'll have to handle inconsistent db states which I'm not willing to do (yet) ... probably for the next mayor version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look of this [Offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689462(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#attributes-and-elements).

**Solution:**

Change the value of `maxAllowedContentLength`.

**Add these code in Web.config(under site/wwwroot on Kudu):**

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="<valueInBytes>"/>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This should work without restart.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I, having an angular app in the wwwroot, thought the configs must come from appsettings, loaded on startup. Now I limited it to 220MB in the backend, and to 200MB from the frontend, just to be sure it doesn't happen again. Thanks again!

Comment: @StefanR. Glad to help.